# select records with only two values from many

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns Users and Details. I need the records only where the user has details with only overdue and Referral but not the user that has overdue, referral , lost and processing.

```
**Users Details**
1560  Overdue
1560  Overdue
1560  Referral
1470  Overdue
1470  Referral
1470  Lost
1470  Processing
1480  Referral
1480  Lost
1480  Processing
1356  Referral
1356  Overdue
1289  Referral 

Output has to be:
1560
1356
1289
```

Comment: What type of RDBMS are you using?
Please use edit the question to use suitable formatting controls.
Please show us the code that you have tried, so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to group the data by `users` and then take only those having the needed `details` but not others

```
select users
from your_table
group by users
having sum(case when details = 'Referral' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when details = 'Overdue' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when details not in ('Referral', 'Overdue') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you **also** want users having just **either** `Referral` OR `Overdue` then do

```
select users
from your_table
group by users
having sum(case when details in ('Referral', 'Overdue') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when details not in ('Referral', 'Overdue') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: You are not retrieving the user with id 1289.

Comment: Good point. I added the query for that too. Not sure what OP really wants here.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!! For the user 1289 I needed it in a separate file so I edited accordingly and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    UD1.user_id
FROM
    User_Details UD1
INNER JOIN User_Details UD2 ON
    UD2.user_id = UD1.user_id AND
    UD2.description = 'Referral'
WHERE
    UD1.description = 'Overdue' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM User_Details UD3
        WHERE
            UD3.user_id = UD1.user_id AND
            UD3.description NOT IN ('Overdue', 'Referral')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. Querying an intermediate Mapping table with a single row indicating which details are in use per user.
Just change [YOUR_TABLE] by the name of your table:

```
SELECT MAPPING.USERS 
  FROM (SELECT USERS   
              ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DETAILS = 'Overdue'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HAS_OVERDUE
              ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DETAILS = 'Lost'       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HAS_LOST
              ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DETAILS = 'processing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HAS_PROCESSING
              ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DETAILS = 'referral'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HAS_REFERRAL    
          FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
         GROUP BY USERS) AS MAPPING
 WHERE (MAPPING.HAS_OVERDUE = 1 OR MAPPING.HAS_REFERRAL = 1)
   AND (MAPPING.HAS_LOST + MAPPING.HAS_PROCESSING) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `not exists`:

```
select distinct t.users 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table 
                  where users = t.users and 
                        details in ('lost', 'Processing')
                 );
```